# Mercurial 3 level repo setup

Tags: mercurial

I have a team for 4 developers starting a new project.

We have win7 & win 2008 network.

What I want to do is each developer to have his local repo on his disk.

When he is done with his job, push his commits to the server repo, so that other developers gets the changes locally.

When there is release done, I would push the final commits and complete release ready from my server to client server which already setup with mercurial.

How to setup such environment with mercurial?

Do I need to share the folder on my server to the four developers?

Comment: it is what mercurial does by default, each developer keeps his own copy of the repository, he commits locally. The central repository is updated after the command Push

Comment: My question is how to set up such two server's one locally in LAN and other remotely on Web? So that I can run the push and pull things.....

Comment: you could use 2 repositories. 1 for everyday development, that is accessible from the developers and you (e.g. hosted on your local network). Only you have access to the production server repository (your clients server). So you export (a .diff file) the changes from the dev repository and import it into the production repo. Seems simple enough to me

Comment: Yes. I agree but, I want to setup the local LAN repo server. So that for local disk I give path of local hg, for internal commits i give local server path. Which should be url and how to get this URL, is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.m1key.me/2010/11/mercurial-server-on-windows-with-apache.html

After some Google search. I got the right place where the answer was.

Have tried this and it works!

Thanks to Michał Huniewicz.